# Miscrosoft Word Label Printing Utility issue

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

Currently I am using Microsoft Word Label Printing Utility to print Labels from my .NET application. I am using following code to print labels.

```
            Word.Application oWord;
            Word._Document oDoc;

            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add();
            var a = oWord.MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument("30 Per Page", "", Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            oWord.Visible = false;
            var table = a.Content.ConvertToTable().Tables[1];
            var innertable = table.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.ConvertToTable();
            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.Bold = 1;

            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.Text = "sdadad";
            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlue;
            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.Font.Size = 15F;
            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.Font.Name = "Verdana";
            innertable.Rows.Add();
            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[2].Range.Text = "fsdfsdfsdf";
            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[2].Range.Font.Bold = 0;
            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[2].Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorBrown;
            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[2].Range.Font.Size = 12F;
            innertable.Columns[1].Cells[2].Range.Font.Name = "Segoe UI";

            var docs=oWord.Documents;
            oWord.Visible = true;
```

Now the problem is that here two documents are created. But I want only document with labels to be open.

Thank you so much in advance...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have closed my standard document manually using following line:

```
oDoc.Close();
```

Thank you...!!

Comment: one suggestion, if you don't mind. As long as you have `oDoc variable` it's less risky to use it when closing document: `oDoc.Close()`. Referring to collection index could result with closing document which you don't want to close.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Please, remove these lines:</strike>

```
Word._Document oDoc;
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add();
```

as they create new standard document in Word application. You don't use it anywhere within your code therefore it seems you don't need it.

**Edit** I think it's not possible to add `MailingLabel document` without any other document opened. Therefore the other suggestion is to close the `oDoc document` after you create MailingLabel. Try the following:

```
//after this line
oWord.Visible = false;
//try to add
oDoc.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer..But I am using oDoc

    `var a = oWord.MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument("30 Per Page", "", Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);`

Comment: No, you are using `a variable` document, not `oWord`. `oWord.Documents.Add()` creates one document and `oWord.MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument(...)` creates second which you work with further in your code.

Comment: Yes I am using 'a' but I am creating my new document as

`oWord.MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument(....)`

Comment: ok, see my edit, I think is necessary to open standard document before you create MailingLabel document... You either close standard one or you need to keep them both.

Comment: Thank you for response but I have already close standard document through code..:)