# Printing to specific area of paper C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, printing

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I am working on a program where I want to print a name unto a label, the labels are in 4 * 2 columns on an 8 1/2 * 14 paper that can be peeled off and stuck to something else. .

**What I have**

So far, when I click print a modal form pops up with 8 buttons in 4 * 2, a representation of the labels on the paper.

**What I need**

Now when I click on any of those buttons, 
I want to pass their location or a button id that is hard coded to a specific location on the page, so if I click the second button in the row, id like that my print be on the second row. Essentially, selecting the button represents what label you will print on.

(let me expound)
lets say the first button is clicked id like to send my name to print on the paper at location

```
x: 0
y: 0
```

Lets say the second button is clicked, id like to send my name to print on the 
paper at location

```
x: 5 (five being halfway)
y: 0
```

and button three will cause the print to happen at

```
x:0
y:-5
```

Comment: If you have Microsoft Office, you could look at [MailingDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.mailinglabel%28v=office.15%29.aspx). There is some code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056117/miscrosoft-word-label-printing-utility-issue

Comment: @PeterBill Is there a nugget I can import with this?

Comment: I hope the answer below helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, create a table to represent the grid of labels and style the `<td>` elements based on the page/label size and add the content you want to print in the first table cell.

Then use jquery to handle the click event of each table cell to re-position the content to the appropriate label.

Finally add a `@media print` style to prevent printing of other elements on the page.

Your view might look like (for a 3 x 2 grid of labels)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="active">
            <div id="content">@Model.SomeProperty</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="message">Click on a table cell to position the content</div>
```

and the script

```js
var content = $('#content');
$('td').click(function() {
    $('td').removeClass('active');
    $(this).append(content).addClass('active');
})
```

and the css

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: dashed grey 1px;
    width: 150px; /*adjust to suit your label size*/
    height: 75px; /*adjust to suit your label size*/
    vertical-align: top;
}
td.active { /*adds an extra visual indicator*/
    border: solid black 1px; 
}
#content {
    padding: 5px;
}
#message {
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: red;
}
@media print
{
    td, td.active {
    border: none;
}
    #message {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsntdgkv/) for a working example

Comment: I am sure the OP wants to fill the form complete before printing, so her selection needs to be sent back to the complete form for printing.

Comment: @RichBailo, No. There is no 'form' (or even if there was it would not matter). This is an intranet app where OP wants to print something onto a label - the label sheet has 2 x 4 rows of labels, and the first 2 labels may have been already been used, so OP needs to position the content in the layout so that it prints to the correct position.

Comment: You are not referencing specific locations on the paper, What if the 4 x 2 she has setup has different heights to each row, of different column widths with a space between columns. that is why you should always use templates to fill, the template can be designed anyway you want for print.

Comment: That point is taken, But if multiple fields need to be filled it would not work she would have to keep putting the paper in the printer for each edit.

Comment: @RichBailo, Your not understanding the issue (and I have the advantage of previously commenting on OP original question relating to this which the OP then deleted)

Comment: @RichBailo, Assume OP has a list of addresses and wants to print one of those addresses onto a label. OP sends the 'address' to the view, but looks over at the printer (which has a sheet with 8 sticky labels on it) and sees that the first label has already been printed on (and probably removed from the sheet). OP needs to be able to position the html so that the address is printed on to the next available label.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any form information,  Just wants to be able to select where on the paper to print.

Comment: Works great, thanks just that @media print doesnt seem to have an effect everything still comes up (probably because i'm printing to pdf? not an actually printer?)

Comment: Why are you printing to a pdf?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Dont have a printer at the moment but it will be to a printer with the sticky label. don't worry you understand completely what I was trying to do

Comment: @StephenMuecke, You are correct and i did not know what was trying to be accomplished here, I apologize. Your solution was easier for that circumstance. Thank you for pointing this out to me. +1 from me.

Comment: @RichBailo, No need to apologize. The question is perhaps not as clear as it should be and I'll edit it later to give a better explanation.

Comment: Do you think i should delete my answer, as i think it might help others looking to complete reports for printing?

Comment: @RichBailo sorry for any confusion caused. Feel free to edit the question

Comment: @RichBailo, No need to delete it (although it might possibly attract some close votes because its not much more that links to other resources - had considered it myself but its borderline, so left it alone)

Answer (score 0):

We use Crystal reports with templates.

You may want to take a look at established reporting systems like:

- FastReport.NET
- Crystal Reports
- DevExpress Reporting

You can do this in code but its easier not to have to edit X and Y areas every time you would like to change the layout. With Crystal we create the data for the report and then gets exported to pdf, the report template can be edited at any time to add more fields, change margins, and adjust page footer and header etc...

here is a link to Structured Print Document utility. [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12450/Structured-Print-Document-utility) might give you somewhere to start.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Once you create your template and let say you created 25 areas for data, you can add a field to your data the represents that area on the template, now when you print your document each item will be in its place on your printout. Link to [Creating a Report with a Selection Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227651(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: With your method, can you state exactly where on the paper you want to print? because im imagining instances where part of the sticky label has arleady been removed and there is  only one more left, so i need a used to be able to direct to rint exactly on it

Comment: Yes you create the template to your parameters, and the data is imported to the parameters you set in the template. here is a link http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-tutorial.htm

Comment: I am familiar with creating crystal reports, I am just unclear in the area of telling the program "where" to print on the paper

Comment: the report does this for you, When you set a template up for printing the data is in the specified location you want to print on the paper you select building the template. another example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/634840/Generating-labels-with-barcode-in-Csharp-using-Cry

Answer (score -1):

I used code in [Miscrosoft Word Label Printing Utility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056117/miscrosoft-word-label-printing-utility-issue) to create this class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.IO;

namespace MKML_Labels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains code to generate a Word document that can
    /// be used to print &/or save the labels.
    /// </summary>
    public class Labels
    {
        #region Fields
        public enum DestinationType : short
        {
            Invalid = 0,
            Print,
            Save,
            Both,
            Open
        }

        private DestinationType destType;
        private string saveFilePath;
        private const int BOLD = 1;
        private const int UNBOLD = 0;

        // L7160 is an Avery type, 21 labels per A4 sheet, 63.5x38.1 mm. See e.g. Amazon ASIN: B0082AWFP8
        private const string LABEL_TYPE = "L7160";

        // The following constants depend on the label type
        private const int NUM_COLUMNS = 6;  // Number of columns on a sheet of labels, 3 labels and 3 separators
        private const int NUM_ROWS = 7; // Number of rows on a page (or sheet of labels)
        private const int NAME_COLUMN_WIDTH = 130;
        private const float NAME_FONT_SIZE = 14.0F;
        private const float NUMBER_FONT_SIZE = 18.0F;
        private const float TEXT_FONT_SIZE = 10.0F;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dest">One of the DestinationType enum values</param>
        /// <param name="path">Full path to the saved file (Word document containing the labels). May be empty if Save not chosen</param>
        public Labels(DestinationType dest, string path)
        {
            destType = dest;
            saveFilePath = path;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Print the labels
        /// Copied and amended from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056117/miscrosoft-word-label-printing-utility-issue
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="creditors">List of creditors</param>
        /// <exception cref=">ApplicationException">Thrown when a Word error occurs</exception>
        public void PrintLabels(List<Creditor> creditors)
        {
            Application wordApp;
            wordApp = new Application();
            Document wordDoc = null;
            Object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            try
            {
                wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add();

                // This adds one page full of a table with space for 21 labels. See below if more pages are necessary
                // I don't know WHY we need 2 documents, but I can't get it to work with only one.
                var newDoc = wordApp.MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument(LABEL_TYPE, "", Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                wordApp.Visible = false;

                // Close the empty, original document
                ((_Document)wordDoc).Close(false, missing, missing);

                var table = newDoc.Content.ConvertToTable().Tables[1];
                int column = -1;
                int row = 1;

                // When row > n * 7, need to add new rows, because we have started a new page
                foreach (Creditor c in creditors)
                {
                    column += 2;
                    if (column > NUM_COLUMNS)
                    {
                        column = 1;
                        row++;
                        if (row > NUM_ROWS)
                        {
                            // After filling the first page, add a new row as required
                            table.Rows.Add();
                        }
                    }

                    // Create an inner table in the cell, with the name in bold and the number right-justified
                    var innertable = table.Cell(row, column).Range.ConvertToTable();
                    innertable.Columns[2].Cells[1].Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
                    innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].SetWidth(NAME_COLUMN_WIDTH, WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustFirstColumn);
                    innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.Text = c.Name;
                    innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.Font.Bold = BOLD;
                    innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorBlack;
                    innertable.Columns[1].Cells[1].Range.Font.Size = NAME_FONT_SIZE;

                    innertable.Columns[2].Cells[1].Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
                    innertable.Columns[2].Cells[1].Range.Text = c.LineNumber;
                    innertable.Columns[2].Cells[1].Range.Font.Bold = UNBOLD;
                    innertable.Columns[2].Cells[1].Range.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorPink;
                    innertable.Columns[2].Cells[1].Range.Font.Size = NUMBER_FONT_SIZE;

                    // Add constants and text for optional data
                    // reference and phone are never in CFS data, and are optional in the Centre Manager database
                    innertable.Rows.Add();
                    Cell cell = innertable.Cell((row + 1), 1);
                    cell.Range.Font.Bold = UNBOLD;
                    cell.Range.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorBlack;
                    cell.Range.Font.Size = TEXT_FONT_SIZE;
                    cell.Range.Text = "Ref. No.: " + c.Reference;
                    innertable.Rows.Add();
                    cell = innertable.Cell((row + 2), 1);
                    cell.Range.Text = "Tel. No.: " + c.Phone;
                }

                if (destType == DestinationType.Save || destType == DestinationType.Both)
                {
                    // Save and close the document
                    // It seems necessary to use a file name without an extension, if the format is specified
                    WdSaveFormat format = (Path.GetExtension(saveFilePath) == ".docx") ? WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument : WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument97;
                    string saveFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFilePath) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(saveFilePath);
                    newDoc.SaveAs(saveFile,
                        format, missing, missing,
                        false, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                        missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                        missing, missing);

                    ((_Document)newDoc).Close(false, missing, missing);
                }

                if (destType == DestinationType.Print || destType == DestinationType.Both)
                {
                    // Print the labels
                    System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog pDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
                    if (pDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        wordApp.ActivePrinter = pDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
                        newDoc.PrintOut();
                    }

                    ((_Document)newDoc).Close(false, missing, missing);
                }

                if (destType == DestinationType.Open)
                {
                    // Don't close the document, the user is editting it
                    wordApp.Visible = true;
                }
            }

            // Does not catch ApplicationException, allow it to be passed to the caller
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException eCOM)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Word document create failed", eCOM);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I have not posted the Creditor class, but you can easily reproduce the properties that are used.

Unfortunately, the system that it was written for has become obsolete, so I can't run the code now.

Comment: OP is creating a web application, not a desktop app. This has nothing to do with OP's issue.